# data loading dataframe as promise

Tags: r

If i try to load a dataset using `data` it gets loaded as `promise`. And if I try to assign that dataset to a variable only the name of dataset gets assigned as a character vector. See screenshot for example. The commands used are:

```r
data("AirPassengers") #this loads AirPassengers as promise
df = data("AirPassengers")
```

[image]

I can also use the same dataframe using `datasets::AirPassengers` which loads/returns in dataframe format.
My question are:

1. What is promise?
2. Why in assignment is only the name of dataframe getting assigned as character when using `data()`.
3. Is there any advanatge of loading data with `data()` compared to the usual `datasets::dataframeName`.